# Помогите с ширеной меню на сайте

Tags: javascript, css, меню, ul

помогите пожалуйста с меню, нужно что бы на всех экранах оно было равно ширине 70% то есть на всю область сайта.
Как можно это реализовать ?? давать новые классы дополнительным ul ??[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://www.samodelkin66.ru/shop/mekhanizirovannye-instrumenty

Comment: У тебя логика меню такая, если ты хочешь цельное меню другого типа, то надо переписывать структуру. Пиши в ВК, если нужно другое меню.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. При чем тут классы списков вложенных? По скриншоту не ясно, открывающийся список должен быть на 70% от ширины контейнера сайта или на 70% ширины экрана? Что мешает при абсолютном позиционировании задать 70 или 100%?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, сейчас кое-как можно догадаться, но каждый догадывается по своему ;)

Comment: да я не прав все размыто, нужно сделать так что бы меню было на всю ширину контейнера (70% от размера экрана) то есть есть 4 уровня меню, первый уровень должен остаться одного размера, а последующие принимать разную ширину, что бы быть прижатыми до края контейнера.

Comment: Сейчас же, под меню имеют фиксированный размер, и соответсвенно при изменении размер  контейнера то вылазят за его края то не доходят до них.